How to diagnose a serial communication crash that happens randomly and very seldom?
I'm connecting to a Lakeshore 336 Temperature controller from Linux Mint via pyserial. My app works relatively well and has operated for months at a time without error. However, it sometimes happen that the device in question stops responding generating the following error message:
device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)
This error was also happening when I ran an earlier version of this GUI on a RaspberriPi4 thus likely not due to the specifics of the runtime environment.
The API for this device inherits from a custom parent class which implements the read function as shown below. Note that I am using semaphores to try to avoid this issue but it still happens! Can someone suggest a way to diagnose (trigger) and perhaps cure this issue?
def read(self, command):
    response = ''
    if self.mutex.tryLock(self.waitLock):
        try:
            if self.ser is not None:
                if self.serialDevice:
                    self.ser.write(bytes(command + self.settings['ending'],'utf-8'))
                    response = self.ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
                else:
                    self.openSocket()
                    self.ser.sendall((command+self.settings['ending']).encode())
                    response, listening = '', True
                    while listening:
                        response += self.ser.recv(128).decode()
                        if self.settings['ending'] in response:
                            response = response.strip()
                            listening = False
                    self.closeSocket()
        except Exception as e:
            print('While reading {} from {}, SerialDevice:read raised:'.format(command, self.settings['name']), e)
            response = ''
        finally:
            self.mutex.unlock()
            #pass
    else:
        print('{} not locking while attempting {}'.format(self.settings['name'], command))
    return response


When it throws this error, what steps do you need to take to recover the device so that you can read from it again?

Restarting the app is usually enough. Sometimes pyserial doesn't recognize the device immediately and I need to try and launch the app several times until it establishes a connection to the Lakeshore temperature controller.
